# How to setup Chef InSpec on AWS by providing 'ARN' instead of Secret Access Key and Access Key Id?

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, inspec

Is there a way to provide ARN instead of setting up credentials. or How to run chef InSpec profiles on different AWS users/accounts by providing only ARN?. I know using Secret Access Key and Access Key Id we can run checks is there any other way?